# Why doesn't select using like query in json string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, sql-server-2019

I can find whit this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE CODE_DESC = '{"title:\["1","2","3"\]"}'
```

But, I can't find this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE CODE_DESC LIKE '%{"title:\["1","2","3"\]"}%'
```

What is different?

I tried like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE CODE_DESC LIKE '% {"title:\["1","2","3"\]"} %'

SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE CODE_DESC LIKE '%{"title:\["1","2","3"\]"}%'
```

but, I can't solve the issue

Comment: which RDBMS are you using MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql. tag it correctly

Comment: Don't use LIKE to search within JSON values in the first place, this is a horrible idea. Use the JSON functions of your database to extract and compare the values you're looking for.

Comment: I using sql-server, and It's not real json data. just string like json in column

Comment: In sql-server you need to escape the `[]` in a like, see: [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Why not use SQL Server's actual JSON tools to parse your JSON instead? Then you might not need to use a `LIKE` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql-server you need to escape the `[]` in a like, see: [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

This works too (replacing the `[` by and `_`, which matches any single character:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE CODE_DESC LIKE REPLACE('%{"title:\["1","2","3"\]"}%','[','_')
```